# If-Then Constraint: If $F(X) > 3$, then $Y = 1$

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

$F(x) = x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$

Scenario: Amongst binary variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$, if more than $3$ are chosen, then another binary variable $Y = 1$. Otherwise, $y = 0$. How can I formulate constraints based on this for a linear programming model?

Thanks!

Comment: According to your specification, $Y=1$ if and only if all four $X_i = 1$. Hence $Y = X_1X_2X_3X_4$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's what I did at first but I need to run this in a linear programming model. Which is why I need to impose if-then constraint but I'm not sure how..

Comment: The knowledge of the whole model, especially the objective function, is usually very helpful when you want to formulate such a constraint. Has y to be minimized or maximized?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that y is to be minimised. This is because there will be a penalty if F(x) > 3 (y = 1).

Comment: In the complete model, there is a value assigned to each x-variable and I need to choose 5 x-variables out of 9 to maximise the total values of the chosen variables, while bearing in mind that if I choose all X1 , X2, X3, X4 I will incur a small penalty. It doesn't mean that I shouldn't choose all these 4 variables because the total values assigned may still be higher to compensate for the penalty. The objective function is (Max. Total values of the 5 chosen variables - 1.2y)

Comment: @Song : this is correct but not linear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :
$$
\mbox{Max } \sum_{i=1}^9 C_iX_i - pY
$$
subject to
$$
X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4 \le 3 + Y
$$
Variable $Y$ takes value $1$ only if all $4$ $X$ variables take value $1$.
You probably also have the following constraint to ensure exactly $5$ $X$ variables are chosen :
$$
\sum_{i=1}^9 X_i = 5
$$

Comment: Yes! That's the solution I was looking for, much obliged!

Comment: There is another problem concerning if-then constraint that I would also like to discuss here:

If someone selects 2 or more items in category A, then they must also select at least 1 item in category B.

X-variables in Category A: X1,X2,X3;
X-variables in Category B: X4,X5,X6,X7,X8

I know I need to introduce another binary variable z that takes the value of 1 if 2 or more X variables in Category A are chosen. This will not go into the objective function, but rather act as a constraint.

Comment: \begin{align*}
X_1+X_2 \le 1+ X_4+X_5+X_6+X_7+X_8 \\
X_1+X_3 \le 1+ X_4+X_5+X_6+X_7+X_8  \\
X_2+X_3 \le 1+ X_4+X_5+X_6+X_7+X_8   \\
X_1+X_2+X_3 \le 2+ X_4+X_5+X_6+X_7+X_8
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi Kuifje, thanks for the speedy reply! Is there a way I could simply this by imposing a if-then constraint? I want to make use of the new binary variable z and come up with something like the first solution you posted above :)

Comment: \begin{align*}
\sum_{i \in A} X_i & \le 1+|A| \delta_A \\
 \delta_A & \le \sum_{i \in B} X_i \\
 \delta_A &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Kuifje, may I ask what exactly is |A|? Is it the same as the big M?

Comment: yup. Here its the cardinality of set $A$. Any big M works. $|A|$ is a "small" big M which is better.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help, Kuifje! Have a good day!

Comment: happy to help.!

Comment: do you think you might be able to enlighten me on this other problem as well? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045069/location-problem-linear-programming) Thanks! :)