# Location problem -- linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a location problem I need help with:

Suppose a boat company wants to operate services between 11 ports in a city. The number of return journeys between port i and port j is denoted by a x-variable (Xij), i and j = 1 to 11. Now I need to impose a constraint such that the number of return journeys between the same pair of ports does not exceed 3. That is, e.g. there can be at most 3 return journeys made between port 1 and port 2.

I know I can do it by Xij + Xji <= 3, but this would result in tons of constraints...

Can anyone come up with a compact form of this constraint? Thank you in advance!

Comment: an alternative is Benders' decomposition, but I'd rather add those 55 constraints

Comment: Think I'd rather do the same as well and keep it simple, thanks!

Comment: It is just one line: $\large{x_{ij}+x_{ji}\leq 3 \ \ \forall \ \ i,j\in \{1,2, \ldots , 11\}}$

Comment: @callculus, this is what I have arrived at too. Thanks for confirming!